# Writing an epsilon proof showing $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} |{\frac{\sin x}{x}|} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

I am trying to write an epsilon proof to show that $$\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} |{\frac{\sin x}{x}|} = 0$$

I'm having a bit of a problem at the moment as to what to include and how to show it properly.
I know I need to show that $$|\frac{\sin x}{x} - L| < \epsilon; \epsilon > 0$$

I don't know if I am allowed to use $L = 0$ in the proof because I have seen people do it before but I don't think your allowed to assume that. Furthermore, I am having trouble removing the magnitude sign with the $| \sin x |$. This is what my proof looks like currently:

For all $\epsilon > 0$, show that $$|\frac{\sin x}{x}- L| < \epsilon$$

Let $$ m = \frac{1}{\epsilon}+1$$
Suppose $$x \ge m$$
Then $$|\frac{\sin x}{x} - L|$$
$$ = |\frac{\sin x}{x}|$$
$$ \le |\frac{1}{x}|$$
$$ < |\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}|$$
$$ = \epsilon$$

Hence $$|\frac{\sin x}{x}- L| < \epsilon$$

Therefore: $$\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} |{\frac{\sin x}{x}|} = 0$$

I would like to know what I have done wrong and what I have missed in this proof. Any answers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are allowed to use that $L=0$ in the proof; indeed, what you are showing is that $L=0$ is the valid, correct, and unique limit for this function. In $\varepsilon-\delta$ proofs, you generally are seeking to show that a certain $L$ is in fact the limit, so you need to know $L$ to begin with.

Comment: $$|\sin x|\le 1 \text{ so } \left| \frac{\sin x}{x}\right| \le 1/x \to 0.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allowed to use L=0. However, what you need to prove is:

$\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists M>0: x>M\Rightarrow \left |\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \right | \lt \epsilon$

To prove that, show that $\left| \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \right | \le \frac{1}{x} \lt \frac{1}{M}$. Then choose $M=\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ to to get the inequality in $\epsilon$.

What I have proved is:

$\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists M>0, M=\frac{1}{\epsilon}:x>M\Rightarrow \left |\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \right | \lt \epsilon$